# Passing `limits` as function arguments

Tags: julia

I'm tryin to build a function that take 2 inputs `limits` and `Function`, so I wrote the below:

```
function Σ(limits, f::Function)
    @show limits
    @show f
end

Σ((i=1:3), :(x->x^2))
```

But it could not run, with the below error:

> ERROR: LoadError: function Σ does not accept keyword arguments

I did not understand shall I change something in the function declaration, or in the function execution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks the error was in passing the `Function`, below the correct code the worked to get this issue solved:

```
function Σ(limits, f::Function)
    prefix, start, stop = limits.args[2].args
    out = 0.0
    for i=start:stop
        out += f(i)
    end
    out
end

result = Σ(:(i=1:6), n->(6n + 2))
@show result
```

[image]

Other 4 ways to solve it, are:

```
# Using Pair
julia> function Σ(limits, f::Function)
           out = 0.0
           start = limits.first
           stop = limits.second
           for i = start:stop
               out += f(i)
           end
           out
       end
Σ (generic function with 1 method)

julia> Σ(1=>6, n->(6n + 2))
138.0
```

And,

```
# Using range
julia> function Σ(range, f::Function)
           out = 0.0
           for i = range
               out += f(i)
           end
           out
       end
Σ (generic function with 1 method)

julia> Σ(1:6, n->(6n + 2))
138.0
```

The last option, can be re-written as:

```
function Σ(range, f::Function)
    out = 0.0
    (for i = range; out += f(i) ; end)
    out
end

result = Σ(1:6, n->(6n + 2))
@show result
```

By using the already existing `sum` function, below is a single line soution:

```
Σ(range, f::Function) = sum(f(i) for i in range)

result = Σ(1:6, n->(6n + 2))
@show result
```

Or, simply as:

```
f(n) = 6n + 2
result = sum(f(n) for n=1:6)
@show result
```

Which also can be simplified to be:

```
f(n) = 6n + 2
result = sum(f, 1:6)
@show result
```